# Javascript hash table vs associative arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable, associative

I'm new to javascript and I cannot find answer about some issues, one is the following:

Why in js would be useful an hash table data structure when we can use objects as associative arrays that is simple to use and have a very good performance?

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean.  JavaScript objects are often _misused_ as PHP-style associative arrays on the assumption that they work the same way as PHP arrays.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Objects in JS _are_ associative arrays. I believe you mean broken approaches like `var a = {}; a[1] = 'something';`, which I've seen many times and is _very likely_ to stem from PHP's horribly disfigured arrays, but this is not using them "as PHP-style associative arrays" but more like exactly the opposite, using associative arrays as indexed ones.

Comment: @lanzz Actually I guess the most common misuse is of actual JS arrays  coerced into being "associative" by adding object properties to them and expecting them to iterate like PHP arrays.

Comment: Oh, thankfully I still haven't seen that in the wild.

Comment: i would do something like this:

Comment: function AssociativeArray()
{
 this.size = 0;
 this.data = {}; //a new object representing the hash
}
AssociativeArray.prototype = {
 insert: function(id,el) {
  if (this.data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {   
   return false;   
  }
  else {
   this.data[id] = el;
   this.size++;
   return true;
  }
 },
 cancel: function(id) {
  if (this.data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
   delete this.data[id];
   this.size--;
   return true;
  }
  else return false; 
 },
 get: function(id) {
  if (this.data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
   return this.data[id];
  }
  else return false;  
 }, 
}

Comment: sorry i'm new to this forum where can i post code properly?

Comment: In ActionScript, HashTables (Dictionary) objects are used to map keys that are non-String Objects to values. This is incredibly useful because you can map Object derivatives to other values. `var bob = {}; myHash[bob] = 1;` This would be one reason to have HashTables in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

> why in js would be useful an hash table data structure when we can use
>   objects as associative arrays that is simple to use and have a very
>   good performance?

The only reason I can imaging to implement an hash table data structure is if you want to preserve the ordering of the elements. The `for…in` loop for objects doesn't guarantee to you in which order the properties ("keys") are returned, even if commonly you can obtain them in chronological order (last added, last returned). But it's not guarantee. For instance, old version of Opera returned the properties in an apparently random order. So, if you need an "ordered" hash table, you need to implement it by yourself.

Comment: so if I don't need to preserve ordering would I ever need any of the classical data structure as B-tress heaps linked lists in javascript?

Comment: You have to see case by case, but generally you can safely assume that if you don't need to preserve ordering and you don't have huge amount of data (that needs faster performance) you can use plain objects.

Answer (score 1):

A javascript hashtable and javascript associative array (and javascript objects) are all the same thing in the underline implementation. These are just different syntax.

So :

```
var a = {};
a.id = "aa";
```

is same as:

```
var a = new Object();
a.id = "aa";
```

Which is is same as:

```
var a = {};
a["id"] = "aa";
```

Comment: i've done some test by filling object using random strings as key and addressing randomly. size of the object(hash was around 1000000 entries). I've noticed that doubling the length of the string used as key the time taken for the algorithm to complete was just 10% more...what does it mean? what hashing function is used to fill object/hash in javascript?

Comment: I don't know, but JS is essentially a spec (ECMAScript). I would assume each JS engine implementes this differently. V8 is open source, so you can check the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Associative arrays and hashtables are the same.
These expressions usually means the same too: dictionary, associative array, hashmap, map, hashtable and... the list goes on.

There is a difference between simple ARRAY and HASHTABLE though.
If you want to search an item in an array, the more items you have inside it, the longer will the search takes.
For example searching an item in an array with 10000 elements could takes 100 times longer than in an array with 100 elements.
With hashtables, no matter how many elements you have, the performance remains the same. (Be it 100 elements or even 99999999 elements...)